# H2: Adding a NOT NULL column to a table with records

Tags: h2

I'd like to add a `NOT NULL` column to a table called `server`. Problem is, the table already contains records. When I invoke `ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN full_discovery_duration BIGINT NOT NULL` H2 complains that `full_discovery_duration` may not be null. I can work around the problem by specifying `DEFAULT 0` but I don't want a default valuefor future inserts. What am I supposed to do?

Should I add the column with a default and then remove `DEFAULT 0` from the column definition in a subsequent statement? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first add the column with a default value, and then set the default to null. Getting rid of the default definition is not possible however as far as I know.

An alternative is to first allow null, then set the values, and later not allow nulls.

```
drop table server;
create table server(id int);
insert into server values(1);
alter table server 
    add column 
    full_discovery_duration bigint;
update server set full_discovery_duration = 0;
alter table server 
    alter column 
    full_discovery_duration set not null;
```

Comment: I got rid of the default definition by executing the following lines: `ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN cached_discovery_duration BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0; ALTER TABLE server ALTER COLUMN cached_discovery_duration BIGINT NOT NULL;` The first line adds the column with a value of `0`. The second line removes the default.

Answer (score 0):

While adding columns to existing tables, it should either be a nullable column or a default value must be specified. And what do you mean by removing the default? how can you remove value from a not null column?

Comment: I meant, should I remove `DEFAULT 0` from the column definition in a subsequent statement? By that time, all rows are guaranteed to already have a non-null value for that column.

Comment: You could use 'alter table ... default null'. It's doesn't remove the default definition, but the effect is the same (at least as far as I know).